# Copy contents of app to desktop programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How can I copy my entire `.app` bundle (`[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]`) to my desktop programmatically?

Here is my code but not helping me.

```
NSString *sourcepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]; 
NSString *destpath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Desktop"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcepath toPath:destpath error:nil];
```

Comment: Does is really make sense to create a clone of your app on the user's hard drive? What are you actually trying to achieve? Some kind of *Windows* like alias on the Desktop?

Comment: Actually i just wanted to know how i can copy programatically in objective c. I tried to use [[NSFileManager defaultManager] but it is not helping me may be somewhere i could be wrong.

Comment: Have you added error handling and `NSLog()`-ged whether an `NSError` is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard `NSFileManager` methods

- [copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtURL%3atoURL%3aerror%3a) or
- [copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtPath%3atoPath%3aerror%3a)

to copy directories as well as files. From Apple's docs:

*When copying items, the current process must have permission to read the file or directory at srcPath and write the parent directory of dstPath. If the item at srcPath is a directory, this method copies the directory and all of its contents, including any hidden files.*

Mind that you have to manually remove an item (file/directory) at the destination with the same name if it already exists or else the copy will fail (again, as per Apple's docs).

Comment: Can you please revisit my question i have edited it by inserting my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it may be this can be helpful for someone.

```
- (IBAction)createShortcut:(id)sender {

 NSString *sourcepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
 NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDesktopDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *theDesktopPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *saveFilePath = [theDesktopPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myApp.app"];
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcepath toPath:saveFilePath error:nil];

}
```

Comment: It's definitely valuable to always check for and handle potential errors for file operations, i.e. I'd check whether the copyItemAtPath: call returns `YES` and provide an `NSError` reference to the method call for error details.